# SwiftUI List in iOS 14 - Remove arrow and separator line

Tags: xcode, list, swiftui

Is there a way to remove the arrow and separator line from a List in a SwiftUI App for iOS 14?

[image]

I tried this but it does not work:

```
init() {
       UITableView.appearance().separatorStyle = .none
       UITableViewCell.appearance().backgroundColor = .clear
       UITableView.appearance().backgroundColor = .clear
       UITableViewCell.appearance().selectionStyle = .none
       UITableViewCell().accessoryType = .none
    }
```

Inside my List there is a ForEach and a NavigationLink.

Bests.

Edit:

My ForEach is this:

```
ForEach(HttpResponseHolder.shared.exoplanetsOrderedByMassWithImage.filter({ searchText.isEmpty ? true : $0.pl_name!.contains(searchText)})) { exoplanet in
                  NavigationLink(destination: ExoplanetDetailView(exoplanet: exoplanet)) {
                    ExoplanetCard(exoplanet: exoplanet)
                  }.buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())
              }.
```

Comment: Would you show your ForEach?

Comment: I added it in my question.

Comment: These are different questions... about arrow, you should hide NavigationLink, like in https://stackoverflow.com/a/64559054/12299030, about separator, you should extend background color, like in https://stackoverflow.com/a/62598818/12299030.