# How can i create a horizontal scrollview combined with multiple clickable buttons?

Tags: swift, xcode, button, swiftui, scrollview

My question is the following i created a horizontal scrollview with different types of images. These images in the horizontal view get created with a `ForEach` command and get loaded on the screen. Now i connected each single picture with a button but i have no idea how to navigate to another Swift file for running there a different code for other stuff.

I will post you the code below maybe you can help me because i really stuck for days. Thanks in advance.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false) {
                HStack{
                ForEach(0..<10){i in
                    cardView(img: "img\(i)").padding(10)
                }

                }
            }
            
        }.background(Image("Apple_Background").resizable().aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill))
    
        }
    }


struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}

struct cardView : View {
    
    
    var img = ""
    var body: some View{
    
        VStack{
            Button(action:  {
                **//Part where i have problems because here the action of the button happens**
            }) {
                
            Image(img).resizable().frame(width: 250, height: 550).position(x: 170, y: 390)
            }
        }
        
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/64559054/12299030? (Possible duplicate)

Comment: I checked it out and it does not really help me to be honest

Answer (score 0):

Use NavigationView and NavigationLink to navigate to another view and remove the button from the card view. Here is the code sample.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack{
                ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false) {
                    HStack{
                        ForEach(0..<10){i in
                            NavigationLink(destination: NextView()) {
                                cardView(img: "img\(i)").padding(10)
                            }
                        }
                        
                    }
                }
                
            }.background(Image("Apple_Background").resizable().aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill))
            
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does the NextView() lead directly to the right file. For example lets say we have three images: Image A, Image B and Image C and we scroll to Image C then we click on it and go to the file of Image C and if we go back and choose Image B then the file of Image C gets loaded. Does this work automatically ? Also there is an error saying he can not find NextView in scope.

Comment: Yes, It will lead directly to the right file. It will work the same as didSelect method in the collection view. NextView is just an example. You have to put your next screen name.

Comment: Man i am really sorry i have no clue because i am a newbie...can you tell me more details like how exactly it works.